# Data binding of an input with a predefined value in Angular

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I wanna have a predefined input form that has the value for the email provider.
I case is not modify, on submit, it should upload to firebase the gmail.com value but it dosen't upload anything unless I delete the value from the input form and rewriting.

```
<input class="button" value="gmail.com" formControlName="emailProvider">
```

Can someone tell what should I modify to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template Driven Forms:

```
<input class="button" [(ngModel)]="value">

class MyComponent {
  value = 'gmail.com'
}
```

Reactive Forms:

```
<input class="button" [formControl]="ctrl">

class MyComponent {
  ctrl = new FormControl('gmail.com');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this might do the trick:

1) Remove the value property from your input;

2) When creating the emailProvider FormControl in your FormGroup instantiation, set the former's initial value to "gmail.com"

```
emailProvider: new FormControl('gmail.com')
```

By doing so, the initial value of the FormControl will be 'gmail.com' and should be able to be overridden by the user's input.